# Accented characters not displayed in ssh session

Tags: command-line, ssh, locale

I'm using kubuntu 20.04 on my desktop and after a fresh install I have an strange behavior when I connect to all of my servers: the files contents with accented characters are not displayed.

For example, the word "**Província**" is displayed "**Prov  ncia**", with two spaces instead of an accented **i** (**í**).

50cm on my left I have my laptop using kubuntu 20.04 too and I don't have this problem.

Here are the locale command info....

Desktop (not displaying characters as expected)...

```
$ locale
LANG=ca_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
C
ca_AD.utf8
ca_ES.utf8
ca_ES.utf8@valencia
ca_FR.utf8
ca_IT.utf8
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Laptop (working perfect)...

```
$ locale
LANG=ca_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ca_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ locale -a
C
ca_AD.utf8
ca_ES.utf8
ca_ES.utf8@valencia
ca_FR.utf8
ca_IT.utf8
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Connecting from my dekstop to one of my servers...

```
# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ca_ES.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

Connecting from my laptop to one of my servers...

```
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf
```

The only difference I see is the message `locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory` when connecting from my desktop. But I don't know where to start to solve the problem.

I'm sure is not a plasma, konsole or kubuntu related problem, because if I not start the desktop (if I login to my desktop in a console) I have the same problem.

I already tried to comment `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (in my laptop it's not commented)

Both laptop and desktop have the same SSH version ...

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem thank's to [this article](https://dausruddin.com/locale-cannot-set-lc_all-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory/)

The steps followed:

```
$ export LC_ALL="ca_ES.UTF-8"
$ export LC_CTYPE="ca_ES.UTF-8"
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then I selected `ca_ES.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8` on `Locales to be generated page` and `ca_ES.UTF-8` on `Default locale for the system environment` (I tried selecting `en_US.UTF-8` and works too).